# Reference a Objective c class in my WatchKit extension (swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit

My main Project is in **Objective c** and i am developing **watchkit** in **Swift**. Now my requirement is that I have to access objective c methods in **swift** (Watchkit extension).

I have created a **bridge** and imported the required class in it.

I was able to access this **objective c** class in **swift** file if it is in the same project. I was not able to access it in **watchkit** extension.

I did added the required class .m file in **watchkit** extension form the **Target Membership** with no use and i was able to access **swift** file in **watchkit** extension after adding it to target membership

So far not being able to solve this. What should i do to access Main app **objective c** class in Watchkit extension (**Swift**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I just had to add the Bridge i created in the Apple Watch Target as well. As soon as i did i was able to access the shared classes in Bridge Header.